# Парсинг: смена заголовков и прокси

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Пишу парсер и у меня есть три списка: `sites`, `headers` и `proxies`, а также функция, которая принимает по одному аргументу. Я хочу что бы после обработки каждых двух url, менялись `header` и `proxy` попарно следующие, но как это реализовать?

```
import requests

proxies = ['some-proxy-1', 'some-proxy-2', 'some-proxy-3']
headers = [
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'},
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'},
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/58.0.1'}
]
sites = ['site-1.ru', 'site-2.ru', 'site-3.ru', 'site-4.ru', 'site-5.ru', 'site-6.ru', 'site-7.ru']

def get_data(url, header, proxy):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=header, proxies=proxy)
    with open('index.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(r.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Comment: "менялись header и proxy" - менялись по какому принципу? - на случайный, попарно следующие, без повторений?

Comment: попарно, на следующую пару

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать генераторы, которые будут перебирать ваши `headers` и `proxies` по 2 штуки.

```
proxies = ['some-proxy-1', 'some-proxy-2', 'some-proxy-3']
headers = [
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'},
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'},
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/58.0.1'}
]
sites = ['site-1.ru', 'site-2.ru', 'site-3.ru', 'site-4.ru', 'site-5.ru', 'site-6.ru', 'site-7.ru']

def get_element_n_times(lst, n):
    while True:
        for elem in lst:
            for _ in range(n):
                yield elem
            
def get_header_and_proxy():
    gen_header = get_element_n_times(headers, 2)
    gen_proxy  = get_element_n_times(proxies, 2)
    while True:
        yield (next(gen_header), next(gen_proxy))

def get_data(url, header, proxy):
    print(url, header, proxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gen = get_header_and_proxy()
    for url in sites:
        get_data(url, *next(gen))
```

На выходе будет:

```
site-1.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} some-proxy-1
site-2.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} some-proxy-1
site-3.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'} some-proxy-2
site-4.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'} some-proxy-2
site-5.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/58.0.1'} some-proxy-3
site-6.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/58.0.1'} some-proxy-3
site-7.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} some-proxy-1
```

Если нужно брать более рандомно, то вот такой генератор:

```
def get_random_element_n_times(lst, n):
    elem = None
    while True:
        elem_new = random.choice(lst)
        if elem_new != elem:
            elem = elem_new
            for _ in range(n):
                yield elem
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы, очень мне помогли!

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

proxies = ['some-proxy-1', 'some-proxy-2', 'some-proxy-3']
headers = [
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'},
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'},
    {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/58.0.1'}
]
sites = ['site-1.ru', 'site-2.ru', 'site-3.ru', 'site-4.ru', 'site-5.ru', 'site-6.ru', 'site-7.ru']


h = random.choice(headers)
p = random.choice(proxies)

for i, url in enumerate(sites):
    print(f'{i} {url} {h} {p}')
        if i%2:
            h_new = random.choice(headers)
            p_new = random.choice(proxies)
            while h == h_new or p == p_new:
                h_new = random.choice(headers)
                p_new = random.choice(proxies)
            h, p = h_new, p_new
```

после пары сайтом сменит заголовок и прокси на новый случайный, не равный предыдущему:

```
0 site-1.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} some-proxy-1
1 site-2.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} some-proxy-1
2 site-3.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/58.0.1'} some-proxy-3
3 site-4.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Firefox/58.0.1'} some-proxy-3
4 site-5.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} some-proxy-2
5 site-6.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'} some-proxy-2
6 site-7.ru {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'} some-proxy-3
```

Comment: Даже у вас в результате получилось, что "новый случайный" оказался равен предыдущему - итого 4 повторения вместо требуемых двух. ;)

Comment: @GrAnd рандом - такой рандом ;) запустил еще пару раз, наткнулся на уникальность... но это не то, согдасен... добавлю проверку на неравенство предыдущему

Comment: А подгонять рандом под правильный результат - не fair play. :)

Comment: "не fair play" то, что @Старк не уточнил до конца принцип смены